# get friends tweet count

Tags: twitter, twitter4j, android-twitter

I'm trying to get the friend's tweets count using twitter4j. so far I was up to getting ID of friends with below code.

```
                accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, oauth_verifier);           
                 SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
                 edit.putString("ACCESS_TOKEN", accessToken.getToken());
                 edit.putString("ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET", accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                 User user = twitter.showUser(accessToken.getUserId());
                 IDs friend_ids  = twitter.getFriendsIDs(accessToken.getUserId(),-1);
                 Log.d(TAG, "friend_ids "+friend_ids.toString());
                 Log.d(TAG, "friend_ids.getIDs() : "+friend_ids.getIDs());
```

I found many posts to get tweets but those are with making a REST call. I would like to know the way to get the tweets count from my above code.

Answer (score 0):

From your code you only gets the id's, so you can't.
But you could use [lookupUsers](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/UsersResources.html#lookupUsers-long:A-) to get info from 100 users at the time, so you can get the status count from that info.